# Comment traduire « worldly » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, vocabulaire

Dans la phrase anglaise suivante :

> *Since I couldn’t join my friends in their worldly activities, I asked them to attend church with me.*

comment peut-on exprimer *wordly* en français :

- mondain (au sens philosophique, mais très peu usité) ;
- matérialiste (avec un risque de perte de sens) ;
- profane ;
- autre chose ?

Comment: *Mondain* n'est pas désuet et me semble approprié à l'exemple.

Comment: Le problème avec « mondain » est qu'il désigne plus souvent des activités liées à la haute société que des activités non religieuses.

Comment: Le mot wordly a plus proche de l'expression "ici bas", puisque c'est dans un context religieux

Comment: @Ibu: bonne remarque (mais avec un « l » en plus à « worldly » ;-))

Comment: Je dirais plutôt "matériel" que "matérialiste"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Leurs activités temporelles* ou *séculières* seraient les traductions directes. Elles reposent toutes deux sur la même opposition religieux/non-religieux que *worldly*.

Par rapport à *profane*: ce dernier marque une opposition avec le fait religieux, alors que *séculier* ne le fait pas (juste une absence). Par exemple, si le curé joue à la pétanque, c'est pour lui une activité séculière, mais qu'on ne pourrait pas qualifier de profane.

Comment: « séculières » est en effet approprié je pense. Quelle différence ferais-tu avec « profane » ?

Comment: @Raphink le clergé séculier n'est pas profane.

Comment: Bonne remarque @Un francophone. Dans le contexte présent cependant, est-ce que ça ferait une grosse différence?

Comment: @Raphink: j'ai édité la réponse suite à ton commentaire. Je pense que profane serait un léger contre-sens dans ce contexte.

Comment: @Rĥaphink, profane s'oppose à religieux, séculier s'oppose à monacal. (Sans entrer dans la multiplicité des acceptions.)

Comment: Que pensez-vous de _laïque_ ?

Answer (score 7):

C'est délicat, et ça va dépendre dans quel contexte (social, pas grammatical) on l'utilise.

Dans certains milieux croyants, dire que quelque chose est « worldly » est assez négatif, voire péjoratif. Je pense que l'équivalent (dans des milieux équivalents) en français serait « du monde ». Ce qui renvoit directement à l'expression :

> « Vous êtes dans le monde mais pas du monde ».

(Donc plus ou moins synonyme de païen !)

Maintenant, dans le contexte de la citation en question : même s'il est fait mention d'église, je ne *crois* pas que cela ait un sens aussi fort (en tout cas, ce serait un manque de délicatesse énorme d'utiliser le sens ci-dessus au sujet de non-croyants et en leur présence).

Donc l'autre sens - le sens plus « worldly » de « worldly », si on veut - s'approche plus de ce que dit F'x - *temporel*, *éphémère*, *léger*, *passager*, *frivole*, d'aucune conséquence durable ou éternelle.

*(En faisant des recherches, je découvre que ce [n'est pas limité](http://fr.islamtoday.net/node/12113) aux chrétiens)*

Comment: Bonne remarques. Dans le contexte de la citation, l'auteur parle de milieux pentecôtistes très charismatiques, donc il s'agit bien de ta première hypothèse. Cela dit, il ne s'adresse pas nécessairement à ce genre de chrétiens, et l'expression "du monde" pourrait dérouter certains lecteurs (notamment francophones, moins habitués à ces mouvements).

Comment: païen et non paien - http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pa%C3%AFen

Answer (score 6):

Je suggère **terrestre**, par opposition au Ciel et aux poursuites plus intellectuelles et spirituelles.

Comment: Du point de vue de l'auteur, le parachutisme amateur est également une activité très « worldly » et pourtant elle n'est pas terrestre ;-) Je pense que le terme pourrait porter à confusion, tant terrestre n'est pas habituellement limité au domaine spirituel.

Comment: Terre-à-terre, peut-être? Quoique, qualifier le parachuitisme d'activité terre-à-terre...

Comment: @Raphink ...entendu parler de *plaisirs terrestres* ? J'ai déjà bu une coupe de champagne en avion, c'est très agréable... ;-)